# Binding model with same id not working with backgrid in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backgrid

I am binding a User model class to backgrid. User model contains id, name, domain. Our aim is display the users corresponding to different domains. Hence same user can be present in multiple domains. In fact we would have records with same id, name but different domain.

Hence while binding only the first record is displayed. How can I display the other records? Please note that in order to maintain uniqueness, I can add a recordId column. But I cannot make any change to existing id column. I noticed that if my id contains unique value, the issues gets resolved. But I cannot make any changes to Id column. Please help.

Divya

Comment: Please, include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Well it's a bit of database theory but it's like having a one-to-many relationship across tables. It's true that the user id's appear multiple times but actually what should be unique here is the pair (user-id, domain-id).

So you could map your user collection to a  let's say UsersWithDomains collection, where each record has a unique id and has user_id and domain_id as attributes.

To map your collection I suggest using the [underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) which return back an array *NOT* so you'll need to keep that in mind not to forget to make them collections again.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you have implemented the UI but you can create a new attribute for example 'data-id' and give it a unique value that's combination of id+domain. Then use the data-id for all manipulation the same way you would do for id. 
Ex: $([data-id='id+domain']) instead of $('#id')

Comment: I used modelId attribute  bound to a  unique model property. I need to add a field in database that yields unique value.which is mapped to the model class property. Thanks you for the answers.